# get child from parent in Qtreeview

Tags: c++, qt, indexing, parent-child, qtreeview

I am developing a Qt application using QTreeView and QFileSystemModel.
I am able to get the parent's child till one level but I am not able to get the parent's child's child.
For eg:

C is child of B,

B is child of A

I am able to get B as A's child but I also want C as A's Child.
I want like this C->B->A.

Can someone give some input regarding this and help me out.
Thanks in advance.

```
//QItemSelectionModel *sel = ui->dir_tree->selectionModel();
QStringList strings = extractStringsFromModel(ui->dir_tree->model(), ui->dir_tree->rootIndex());

QFileSystemModel* model = (QFileSystemModel*)ui->dir_tree->model();
QModelIndexList indexlist = ui->dir_tree->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
QVariant data;

//QList<QModelIndex> modelindex(indexlist);

int row = -1;

for(int i=0; i<indexlist.size();i=i+4)
{
    QModelIndex mi=indexlist.at(i);
    info1 = model->fileInfo(mi);
    QString childstr = info1.filePath();
    QString childname = info1.fileName();

    QModelIndex mi2= indexlist.at(i).parent();
    info = model->fileInfo(mi2);
    QString parentstr = info.filePath();
    QString parentname = info.fileName();
    QStringList childlist;
    for(int j=0;j<model->rowCount(indexlist.at(i));j++)
    {
        QModelIndex mi3 = indexlist.at(i).child(j, 0);
        info2 = model->fileInfo(mi3);
        QString childrenstr = info2.filePath();
        childlist << childrenstr;
        qDebug()<<"parents' children"<<childrenstr<<j;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `QModelIndex miA = miC.parent().parent();`?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but if incase there is one more level then? if i want like this D->C->B->A then the method you suggested will not help. I want to check recursively but i am not getting how can I implement it over here.

Comment: The inner "for loop" helps me to get all the children of parent. But if the children also has children that I am unable to get. So I want all the children(including their children) of the parent.

Comment: You are going to have to rephrase your question then.  Are you asking how to get all the children recursively, or all ancestors?

Comment: Yes, I want all the children recursively or all parents of particular child, any way would work.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use recursion for this kind of thing:

```
void MyTreeView::GetAllChildren(QModelIndex &index, QModelIndexList &indicies)
{
    indicies.push_back(index);
    for (int i = 0; i != model()->rowCount(index); ++i)
        GetAllChildren(index.child(i,0), indicies);
}
```

Usage (from somewhere inside the tree view):

```
QModelIndexList list;
GetAllChildren(model()->index(0,0), list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting all children breadth-first:

```
QModelIndexList children;

//  Get top-level first.
for ( int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); ++i ) {
    children << model->index( i, 0 );  //  Use whatever column you are interested in.
}

// Now descend through the generations.
for ( int i = 0; i < children.size(); ++i ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < model->rowCount( children[i] ); ++j ) {
        children << children[i].child( j, 0 );
    }
}
```

Getting all parents from a child:

```
QModelIndexList parents;
parents << child.parent();
while ( parents.last().isValid() ) {
    parents << parents.last().parent();
}
```

Please note, I haven't tried these samples!

Comment: Hi, thanks. But there is no function like "model->child(i,0)", also the function model->rowCount() requires a QModelIndex argument. Is there something missing?

Comment: Woops, I've updated.  `model->rowCount()` has a default arg of an invalid index, which represents a 'parent' of the top-level.

Comment: Hey your code is producing the same result as mine code. Its not iterating the child index. For eg: Have a folder named "Downloads", in it, it has "Complete" Folder and in it, it has "Sample" Folder and it includes "Test" Folder. When I click on "Downloads" in my Qtreeview I want to display its child i.e. "Complete" and also "Sample" and "Test". But mine code and your code displays only "Complete" and not "Sample" and "Test".

Comment: Get it to print out how many children it thinks are in each row.  I must say I had a problem with `QDirIterator` last year where it wouldn't find all the files in a directory, I migrated to Boost's equivalent it worked fine - perhaps they use the same mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Delete
    QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> selected = ui->twg->selectedItems();
    QTreeWidgetItem *item = selected.first();
    QTreeWidgetItem *parent = item->parent();
    if(parent) {
        int index = parent->indexOfChild(item);
        delete parent->takeChild(index);
    }

//Add
QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> selected = ui->twg->selectedItems();
QTreeWidgetItem *item = selected.first();
QTreeWidgetItem *parent = item->parent();
if(parent) {
    QTreeWidgetItem *tmp = new QTreeWidgetItem(parent);
    tmp->setText(0, "Dude");
    parent->addChild(tmp);
}
```

Comment: that's more useful to explain a little about your answer.